# Filter Values in ChangeContentType Control

Tags: content-type, custom-form

I am using the SharePoint:ChangeContentType control (which renders as a DropDownList in New/Edit modes). I need to manipulate the values that are present in the rendered DropDownList in the CodeBehind. I can't manipulate them with JavaScript/jQuery because I will get a ViewState exception.

I can get a reference to the ChangeContentType control but can't cast it as a DropDownList and therefore I can't get a refernce to the items in it in order to add/remove stuff.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to find `ContentTypeChoice` control in [SharePoint:ChangeContentType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.changecontenttype.aspx) control:

```
DropDownList dropDownList = (DropDownList) control.TemplateContainer.FindControl("ContentTypeChoice");
```

Comment: Awesome! Now that I have a valid reference why is the items collection empty in the debugger? I am referencing this in Page_Load so I would assume that all of the items in the ChangeContentType control would have been initialized already. 

Do I need to create a custom control that inherits from ChangeContentType and manipulate the values in the items collection from the Init of the custom control?

I was REALLY hoping to avoid that.

Comment: I figured it out. I just attached an EventHandler to the dropDownList.PreRender event and then implemented the code required to manipulate the Items collection there.

Comment: Ami, i also think OnPreRender event is the right place to manipulate control, since ContentTypeChoice  is populated in OnLoad event

Comment: So this works on a regular ASPX page but I can't use the code for a UserControl:

Comment: This works on a regular ASPX page but I can't use the code in a custom form template. The ChangeContentType control property is not set in the Designer file and I can't get a reference to it. Any thoughts?

Comment: Never mind. For some reason I was getting a null reference exception but now it works. Very strange.